# Get All users from Sharepoint Group - exclude the hidden System Account

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to get all users in a Sharepoint group as they appear on the screen (the standard sharepoint screen where you view the list of users for the group).

However, when I use the Users property of the group, it is retrieving an additional user with name of "System Account", which seems to be the site admin.

Is there a way to get all users and exclude this user. Also, a strange thing is that the IsSiteAdmin property of this SPUser is false.

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to solve this? thanks!

Comment: thanks for your comment. unfortunately not, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logged in as SystemAccount (applicaton pool identity or farm account) then it is added automatically as a member to that group.

Don't create groups while logged in as system account to avoid such situations.

To remove System Account from all the groups in a site collection check  [this post](https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/remove-system-account-from-a-sharepoint-group-with-powershell/).